# Examples of idelic Artin map

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I do not know of any source on class field theory which explains the idelic Artin map through a couple of examples.

Please provide me some.

Comment: The idelic Artin map is defined by restriction to a subgroup of ideals then applying the ideal Artin map...